# process with different name on windows

Tags: windows, process

I have a process on windows, lets call it DDD.exe .
  That process runs several times parallel. I open the task manager. I would like to change the name of the process that runs that it will contained also a number.
For instance: DDD1.exe , DDD2.exe etc' .
Can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Imagine what malware could do with this capability.

Answer (score 0):

That field is the file name of the executable. The only way to change it is to make copies of the executable with different names. I don't imagine you want to do that.

I personally use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) as my task manager. When you hover over an entry in Process explorer, a hint window is displayed containing the command line passed to the process. You could make use of this feature if you passed a benign ID parameter when you created each process.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to differentiate between the instances, it's already there, in the process's [PID column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382713.aspx).